# Erroneous file size while in 'with open'

Tags: python

Trying to compare if the last value is equal to the current value. Here is my code:

```
   with open('unfiltered_data.csv', 'r') as inp:
        for row in csv.reader(inp):
            if row[2] == "FÃ¶rvÃ¤rv" and row[1] != '':
                with open('last.txt', 'w') as f:
                    if os.stat('last.txt').st_size == 0:
                        f.write(row[1])
                    else: <code>
```

Outside of the with open(file) the logic works, st_size does not equal zero. What am I doing wrong? How can I accomplish this task without using a file or otherwise?

All help is much appreciated.

Comment: use `f.tell()` to get the current position in the file in bytes. `st_size` won't update until buffered data is `flush`'d to the file or the file is closed. This is expected behavior

Comment: `open('last.txt', 'w')` is going to truncate last.txt if it exists – what’s the intent behind checking its size after doing that?

Comment: @Aaron Alright but how do I check if file is empty?

Comment: @Ry- Ok, purpose is to check if data has been updated. Data is gathered via the web.

Comment: you check the stats of the file before you open it

Comment: where are you comparing the last value to the current value?

Comment: There's no need to check the file size. Just read the file to get the last value. If the file is empty, you'll read an empty string, and it won't be equal to any current value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's how to get file length in various scenarios:**

- If the file is not open (anywhere), it's fine to use `os.stat().st_size`.
- If you just opened the file in write mode `with open(filename, "w") as f:`, the file will be empty.
- If you have written to said file since opening, calling `f.tell()` will "tell" you the current position of the "cursor" which will be at the end of the file (and hence be equal to the length of the file) unless you specifically `f.seek()` somewhere earlier in the file.
- If you open the file in append mode `"a"`, the cursor will start out at the end of the file, and `f.tell()` will again tell you the length of the file().
- If you open the file in read mode `"r"`, the cursor will start out at the beginning of the file. Calling `f.tell()` will therefore start out at 0, but after the file has been read, the cursor will once again be at the end, and `f.tell()` will give you the file length. If you don't want the data itself, you can `f.seek()` to the end instead of reading the file contents.